# What is Docker storage driver

Tags: linux, docker

I am learning Docker storage and I am not clear about Docker storage drivers.

1. What is docker's storage driver in layman's terms?
2. How is it different than Backing Filesystem that docker info command shows?
3. If someone wants to write his own storage driver? How to do that?

Comment: Two downvotes without any comment/justification. Please let me know what is wrong with this question.

Comment: Maybe they assume you might put up questions more specific, since your questions seem to be difficult to answer with short paragraph. Have a look at the answer you've accepted,  it's more like a guideline than an answer. Next time you question here, try again... Oh, I didn't give you down vote...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you go and look at the presentation from one of the docker developers: http://www.slideshare.net/Docker/docker-storage-drivers

> What is docker's storage driver in layman's terms?

When you use the `FROM` command in a `Dockerfile` you are referring to a base image. Rather than copy everything in a new image, you will share the contents (a.k.a. fs layers); this is what is known as a copy-on-write (holy cow!) filesystem. The docker storage driver is just which kind of COW implementation to use (`AUFS`, `BTRFS` ...). If you imagine your images as layers and depending on each other, you get a graph.

> How is it different than Backing Filesystem that docker info command shows?

Same difference between logical and physical representation. The filesystem may be mounted as `ext4` (where docker is installed) but used by `docker` daemon to leverage COW semantics.

> If someone wants to write his own storage driver? How to do that?

Go and take a look at the `graphdriver` (manages the graph of layers).

https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/daemon/graphdriver